# Setting variables with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am creating a language with regex this is my code so far:

```
    import re

    outputf=r'output (.*)'
    inputf=r'(.*) = input (.*)'
    intf=r'int (.*) = (\d)'
    floatf=r'float (.*) = (\d\.\d)'

    def check_line(line):
        outputq=re.match(outputf, line)
        if outputq:
            exec ("print (%s)" % outputq.group(1))

        inputq=re.match(inputf, line)
        if inputq:
            exec ("%s=raw_input(%s)"%(inputq.group(1), inputq.group(2)))

        intq=re.match(intf, line)
        if intq:
            exec ("%s = %s"%(intq.group(1), intq.group(2)))
            print x

        floatq=re.match(floatf, line)
        if floatq:
            exec ("%s = %s"%(floatq.group(1), floatq.group(2)))


    code=open("code.psu", "r").readlines()

    for line in code:
        check_line(line)
```

So it works great but in my file, here is my code:

```
int x = 1
output "hi"
float y = 1.3
output x
```

But when i read line 4, it says the variable x is not defined. How can I set it up so it can also print variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When exec() is called it optionally can be passed the global and local dictionaries of variables that it will use.  By default, it uses `globals()` and `locals()`.

The problem is, you are using `exec()` to set a variable like `x = 1` in your example.  That does get set, and you can will see it in `locals()`.  But after you leave the function, that variable is gone.

So, you'll need to save the `locals()` after each `exec()` call.

EDIT:

I was writing this addendum as you answered it yourself, so I figured I post it anyway...

Here's a simple example that fails (same error as your example):

```
def locals_not_saved(firsttime):
    if firsttime:
        exec("x = 1")
    else:
        exec("print(x)")

locals_not_saved(True)
locals_not_saved(False)
```

And here's a modified version that saves and reuses the `locals()` by saving them as an attribute to the the function - that's just one way to do it, YMMV.

```
def locals_saved(firsttime):
    if not hasattr(locals_saved, "locals"):
        locals_saved.locals = locals()

    if firsttime:
        exec("x = 1", globals(), locals_saved.locals)
    else:
        exec("print(x)", globals(), locals_saved.locals)

locals_saved(True)
locals_saved(False)
```

Comment: or you could do:  exec ("global %s; %s = %s"%(floatq.group(1), floatq.group(1), floatq.group(2)))

Comment: @AaronGill-Braun nope, `global` can only be used inside functions